# Understanding Field access expression

Tags: java, android

Here's the code for the class GameObject.java:

```
package com.badlogic.androidgames.gamedev2d;

import com.badlogic.androidgames.framework.math.Rectangle;
import com.badlogic.androidgames.framework.math.Vector2;

public class GameObject {
    public final Vector2 position;
    public final Rectangle bounds;

    public GameObject(float x, float y, float width, float height) {
        this.position = new Vector2(x,y);
        this.bounds = new Rectangle(x-width/2, y-height/2, width, height);
    }
}
```

Code for Rectangle.java:

```
package com.badlogic.androidgames.framework.math;

public class Rectangle {
    public final Vector2 lowerLeft;
    public float width, height;

   public Rectangle(float x, float y, float width, float height) {
       this.lowerLeft = new Vector2(x,y);
       this.width = width;
       this.height = height;
   }
}
```

Code snippet for Vector2.java:

```
package com.badlogic.androidgames.framework.math;

public Vector2(float x, float y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
```

And a code snippet for SpatialhashGrid.java:

```
package com.badlogic.androidgames.gamedev2d;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.util.FloatMath;

public class SpatialHashGrid {
    List<GameObject>[] dynamicCells;
    List<GameObject>[] staticCells;
    int cellsPerRow;
    int cellsPerCol;
    float cellSize;
    int[] cellIds = new int[4];
    List<GameObject> foundObjects;

    public int[] getCellIds(GameObject obj) {
        int x1 = (int)FloatMath.floor(obj.bounds.lowerLeft.x / cellSize);
        int y1 = (int)FloatMath.floor(obj.bounds.lowerLeft.y / cellSize);
        int x2 = (int)FloatMath.floor((obj.bounds.lowerLeft.x +     obj.bounds.width) / cellSize);
        int y2 = (int)FloatMath.floor((obj.bounds.lowerLeft.y + obj.bounds.height) / cellSize);

    if(x1 == x2 && y1 == y2) {
        if(x1 >= 0 && x1 < cellsPerRow && y1 >= 0 && y1 < cellsPerCol)
            cellIds[0] = x1 + y1 * cellsPerRow;
        else
            cellIds[0] = -1;
        cellIds[1] = -1;
        cellIds[2] = -1;
        cellIds[3] = -1;
    }
```

Whenever I read any Java book they always mention the Law of Demeter. Isn't the line :

```
int x1 = (int)FloatMath.floor(obj.bounds.lowerLeft.x / cellSize);
```

violating this law? Since I never used convention like this, I can't seem to understand what does this line mean? How can 3 objects be used in the same line with the dot(.) operator?

Comment: Do you know what a field access expression is?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis no, I don't know what that means.

Comment: It is a way to cascade objects to reach to the right-most object. You could do it in separate lines too. Each object has a field which is again an object which can have a field. So the expression is valid.

Comment: @AnindyaDutta the only thing I cannot seem to understand is , how objects of different classes can be used in the same line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int x1 = (int)FloatMath.floor(obj.bounds.lowerLeft.x / cellSize);
```

The above line is an assimilation line of the following:

```
Rectangle bounds1 = obj.bounds;
Vector2 lowerLeft1 = bounds1.lowerLeft;
float xtemp = lowerLeft1.x;
int x1 = (int)FloatMath.floor(xtemp / cellSize);
```

Instead of declaring separate variables, the developer chose to cascade them into one line. Since they are `public` variables, they can be accessed via the `dot` operator, viz. `object.variable`.

Comment: OK. I understand what you are saying, but doesn't this mean: objectA.objectB.objectC.variable? And all the objects from different classes?

Comment: Yes, it does. What is your doubt?

Comment: I am sorry, I have never used this convention of chaining of objects before, that's why I am getting confused. I have written code with chaining methods but not objects.

Comment: Method calls return a datatype. An object is also a datatype. So both of them fit in the expression equivalently.

Comment: OK, thanks a lot. Last question, is there a rule as to which objects I can chain and which I cannot? Is it limited to the same package classes?

Comment: You can chain any member of a class as long as you have access to it. So in this case since the access is `public` you can access it anywhere. If it were `private` then you could only access it in the class where the object was declared.

Answer (score 1):

It might be that [Information hiding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding) is not quite a requirement in the example.

Answer (score 1):

```
class A {
  public int b;
}
A a = new A();
int c = a.b;
```

The dots mean access the member named. In my case access the member b of the object a.

It's rarely seen because it involves directly accessing the member variable of an object, which is almost always bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

In short, Law of Demeter suggests that you should only "talk to your immediate friends; don't talk to strangers."

In your example, the statement  `obj.bounds.lowerLeft.x` breaks this principle, because there instead of only accessing properties of the `obj` variable, also a distant variable in the object graph (`x`) is read directly.

This is possible because Java supports chaining calls to member variables (and non-void methods). However, "talking to strangers" like this is an anti-pattern because it makes *refactoring* your code difficult; small changes like renaming variables can break code in other classes that use the variable directly